# Publishing OG actions on fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-page

I'm trying to publish action (my custom OG action) as fanpage.

I have my fanpage access token for app and in OG Explorer I got error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) App is not allowed to publish actions for pages", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 10
  }
}
```

Is there any possibility to do this, because I don't understand if 'my' app is not allowed do publish, or all apps can't do this ?

Comment: You are going to need to use a page access token to do this. In order to get your page token you'll need to grant your application the `manage_pages` permission... You can read more about access tokens [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/access-tokens-and-types/).

Comment: I know, I have fanpage access token from my app - and ofcourse i used it.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't see it was an action... Thought it was just a regular post... I don't think that Pages can perform actions like regular users can... In the same way that a page can not "poke" other pages or users... I could be wrong though... not 100% sure.

Comment: Correct, OG actions are meant to be undertaken by real people, not entities like pages.

Answer (score 0):

The message explains in full the reason. Open Graph actions at the current date are meant for real users not fan pages.

> App is not allowed to publish actions for pages